# Delete top margin of the UIView inside MvxViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

When I'm using regular UIViewController at Xamarin.iOS project everythis stretch to fit the screen. But when I change inheritance to mvvmcross base viewcontroller I got strange margin which I couldn't fix.

[image]

My code is pretty straight forward.
I don't have any xib or storyboards

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    View = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red };
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
    View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be Navigation controller which could be easily hidden by NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true